# Django - Change python version

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, wsgi

I am running a Django 1.11 server that was initially started with Python2.7
I am trying to make it run on Python3, so I've decided that it would be easier to start a new project.

I created a virtualenvironment with Python3 as the main version, then I ran django-admin. When I tried to see the error logs, it said that the version I was using was from python2.7 as below.

```
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/var/www/realtranslation',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

I'm using apache2 and wsgi also, so I deleted wsgi for python 2.7 and started using wsgi for python3

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

This changed my python version, but now when I try installing packages with pip3 and including them in my settings.py installed app it won't find them.

```
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/var/www/realtranslation',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

This are my server logs:

```
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:03.821217 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1348:tid 139948324480896] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155121 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422] mod_wsgi (pid=3840): Target WSGI script '/var/www/realtranslation/realtranslation/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155220 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422] mod_wsgi (pid=3840): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/realtranslation/realtranslation/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155905 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155957 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/var/www/realtranslation/realtranslation/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155962 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155968 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155971 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155977 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155979 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155984 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155987 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155992 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.155995 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     module = import_module(entry)
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156000 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156002 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156007 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156013 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156018 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon Jun 19 21:28:58.156033 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3840:tid 139948153894656] [client 186.167.250.100:16422] ImportError: No module named 'allauth'
```

This is my wsgi file:

```
"""
WSGI config for realtranslation project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "realtranslation.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I don't see any code in that wsgi wrapper that activates the virtualenv. The [modwsgi docs](http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html) have more information, including for Python 3 venv (which doesn't install an `activate_this.py`).

Comment: @dhke Suppose I don't want to use venv

Comment: You still need to modify`sys.path` so that your project directory appears there and Python can find your applications, i.e. `sys.path.insert(0, APP_HOME)` where `APP_HOME` is the root of your Django project.

Comment: Can you include your apache2 `.conf` file as well?